# How to do HTTP Requests with headers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, get

How to do HTTP Requests with headers in javascript?
For example -

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" 'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/servers'
```

How do I this kind of stuff in javascript?

Comment: Do you just mean how to make a request? Install something like axios and read the docs.

Comment: It depends on which API you are using. All the built-in ones have a feature that makes that possible, as do most of the library which wrap those build-in APIs. Opening the documentation for whichever API you're using, pressing Ctrl+F and typing "header" will probably solve the problem for you.

Comment: `fetch()` takes headers. Docs are on MDN!